# Swiper Nested Slider - Prevent Parent from Sliding while sliding nested Slider

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm having a problem with nested Swiper slider.
I would like to prevent sliding parent slider while I'm hovering over inner slider and sliding it.

```
var parentSwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
direction: 'horizontal',
slidesPerView: 1,
mousewheelControl: true,
speed: 300,
mousewheel: {
    releaseOnEdges: true,
},
nested: true, // Enable nested swiper
});

var innerSwiper = new Swiper('.inner-swiper-container', {
    direction: 'horizontal',
    spaceBetween: 50,
    mousewheelControl: true,
    speed: 300,
});
```

When I hover over innerSwiper sliden and roll the mousewheel both parent and child sliders move.
When I go back to the slide where I have nested slider, since parent is first and has no where to go back, I can slide back nested sliders.